# Multiple date columns in order of first upcoming date Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. Multiple Dj's are making music on our radio but we wanted to make a timetable so we made lots of columns with info about the DJ but also containing twelve datetime stamps in twelve different columns.

Problem is, how do I select the first upcoming date? Or how do I select the first column which date is higher then the current date. And the following ones.

if this is solved I had another problem echo'ing it because how does the script beneath it know which variable I used.

I've used the following variables and columns: $date1, $date2, $date3 etc.

Thx!

Comment: can you refactor your database?

Comment: If you can paste your table structure, we could help you much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT dj, 'date1' whichdate, if (date1 >= now(), date1, null) nextdate
    union
    SELECT dj, 'date2' whichdate, if (date2 >= now(), date2, null) nextdate
    union
    SELECT dj, 'date3' whichdate, if (date3 >= now(), date3, null) nextdate
    union
    SELECT dj, 'date4' whichdate, if (date4 >= now(), date4, null) nextdate
    union
    SELECT dj, 'date5' whichdate, if (date5 >= now(), date5, null) nextdate
    union
    SELECT dj, 'date6' whichdate, if (date6 >= now(), date6, null) nextdate
    union
    SELECT dj, 'date7' whichdate, if (date7 >= now(), date7, null) nextdate
    union
    SELECT dj, 'date8' whichdate, if (date8 >= now(), date8, null) nextdate
    union
    SELECT dj, 'date9' whichdate, if (date9 >= now(), date9, null) nextdate
    union
    SELECT dj, 'date10' whichdate, if (date10 >= now(), date10, null) nextdate
    union
    SELECT dj, 'date11' whichdate, if (date11 >= now(), date11, null) nextdate
    union
    SELECT dj, 'date12' whichdate, if (date12 >= now(), date12, null) nextdate
)
WHERE nextdate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY dj, nextdate
```

Comment: You asked "how does the script beneath it know which variable I used?". That column tells it which it is. It would probably be better if you normalized your schema, so that these were different rows. Then you wouldn't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would get the next (upcoming) date from a database by doing a normal SELECT statement but limiting the results to "1" and using a WHERE clause to get the date, along with ensuring the results are sorted in order by date.

In my example below, I have selected the record from the DB with the next date which may also include today itself. if you don't care about today's records, then just change the 'newtime' variable in the select command to 'todaydate'.

```
$todaydate = date('Y-m-d');
$newdate = strtotime ( '-1 day' , strtotime ( $todaydate ) ) ;
$newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );

SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > '$newdate' ORDER BY table.`date`ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The whole point of his question is that there are 12 date columns, not just 1. How does this answer address that?